# Can't connect to mysql using localhost

Tags: mysql, drupal, osx-elcapitan

I'm using Mac and latest MySQL. Recently I've updated OS to El Capitan and now realised that 'localhost' as a name does not work anymore, but only 127.0.0.1.

Is there some settings where I can define for mysql that localhost is actually 127.0.0.1?

Here is the message in Drupal (it's because I'm using localhost).

[image]

This settings in Drupal are using in order to connect to mysql database.
If I use localhost it does not work, if I use there 127.0.0.1 - it works well.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific i don't get your problem, you can't connect or mysql can't start?

Comment: Can you check your hosts file. If 127.0.0.1 is working but localhost does not, then maybe the localhost entry is missing from the hosts file. I'm not a Mac user but I believe the hosts file is located at /private/etc/hosts

Comment: localhost is there (in hosts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I followed option #1 under "THREE options to fix MySQL 5.6" and my errors went away - [Mysql 5.6 headaches on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813630/mysql-5-6-headaches-on-mac-osx).